# How to set datepicker value to selected date after page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I have one datepicker having `id="from_dt"` and button with `id="fromToDate"`.
When i select a date from the datepicker and click the button, the page will load and then i want to set that selected datepicker value to a textbox.

```
<input class="form-control" id="from_dt" type="text" placeholder="From Date" value="" readonly>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline btn-primary btn-xs" id='fromToDate' value="Search" onclick="getEventListWithDateTime()">
```

and this is button click function :

```
function getEventListWithDateTime() {
$("#eventListDatePickerForm").attr( "action", "/eventList/" + $("#from_dt").val() + "/" + $("#to_dt").val());
```

}

Comment: And is this a form submit, or does the `getEventListWithDateTime` somehow reload the page? What serverside language is being used?

Comment: this is form submit event...it will fetch the data from database from that date

Comment: i am working with SCALA...with html & javascript

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation of jquery UI datepicker it says: `$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "setDate", "10/12/2012" );`

See: [Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate)

Comment: actually i want the selected date to be displayed after page load..not the predefined date...

Comment: Do you want the page to be reloaded after date select?

Comment: I think you should get that from the POST value's like adeneo us suggesting.

Comment: @VPK once i will select date then click the button ok...then page will be reloaded.. after that i want to set previous selected date to that textbox which was selected before page load

Answer (score 0):

If you post your date then it will fetch by using `$_POST`

```
var $date = isset($_POST["date"])?$_POST["date"]:"";
<input value="$date" class="form-control" id="from_dt" type="text" placeholder="From Date" value="" readonly>
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getEventListWithDateTime() {
$("#eventListDatePickerForm").attr( "action", "/eventList/" + $("#from_dt").val() + "/" + $("#to_dt").val());
```

}

This is my function on button click event

Answer (score 0):

Try a workaround for this, put your date value in hidden input field in `onchange` event of date field,

```
$('#from_dt').change(function(){
  var fromDate = $(this).val();
  $('#fromDate').val(fromDate);
}

<input type="hidden" id="fromDate">
```

And in `$(document).ready()`

```
if($('#fromDate').val() !== undefined || $('#fromDate').val() != '') {
  $(this).val($('#from_dt').val());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mike's answer helped me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28061283/6517383

For using a dynamic variable just use:

```
var dateToBePrefilled = "10/12/2012";
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "setDate", dateToBePrefilled );
```