# how to change default value of jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have two date picker one for start date another one for end date

I want to change the end date selector value to the start date value after setting the start date value how can I achieve that ?

here is my code:

```
jQuery('#dp-rtd>input[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker({
  trigger: '#dp-rtd',
  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  startDate: Date.now(),
  pick: function () {
    jQuery('#dp-rtr').click()
}
});

jQuery('#dp-rtr>input[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker({
  trigger: '#dp-rtr',
  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  startDate: Date.now(),
  pick: function () {
    jQuery('body').click()
  }
});
```

Comment: `jQuery('#dp-rtr>input[data-toggle="datepicker"]').).datepicker("setDate", $('#dp-rtd>input[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker('getDate')).trigger("change");`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8147201/2181514 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28061236/how-to-set-datepicker-value-to-selected-date-after-page-load